# macOS menubar application: main menu not being displayed

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, background-process, menubar

I have a statusbar application, which runs in the menu bar. Therefore I set `Application is agent (UIElement)` to `true` in the `info.plst`. That results in no dock icon and no menu bar for my application.

However, I also have a preference window that the user can open from the statusbar menu. Here is how I open it:

```
if (!NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)) {
    print("unable to set regular activation policy")
}
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
if let window = preferencesWindowController.window {
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
}
```

The window shows up as expected, but the application's main menu bar with *File*, *Edit* and so on, does not show up. Only if I click on another app and come back to my app, the menubar is being displayed.

I noticed, that if I change the value in the `info.plst` to `false` and use `NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.accessory)` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching()`, it has the same result. However, if I call `NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.accessory)` with a timer a few milliseconds after `applicationDidFinishLaunching()` is being called, it works and the main menu is being displayed as expected. This however has the side effect that the app icon pops up in the dock for a few seconds (until the timer is being fired), which is not a nice user experience.

Does anyone have an idea what else I could try? What is happening when I switch the active app, that I am not doing in code?

I am using Version 8.2.1 (8C1002) on macOS 10.12.2 (16C67)

Thanks!

Comment: "The window shows up as expected" I assume the window also becomes first responder and doesn’t look like in the background or something. Correct?

Comment: I've run into this issue as well with my app.  You're not alone :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my **workaround** solution for now:

As I wrote in the question, if I click on another app and come back to my app, the menubar is being displayed. I am simulating this when I try to show the preference window:

```
    NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

   if (NSRunningApplication.runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.dock").first?.activate(options: []))! {
       let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(200)
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {                 
       NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
            NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
       }
   }
```

This is not a perfect solution. If I don't find a better solution, I will file a bug.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and I haven't found a working solution.  Where do you run the above code?  In the applicationDidFinishLaunching function of the AppDelegate ?

Comment: Hi! Did you ever find a better solution to this?

Comment: No, I did not. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fix (or workaround) from OP. The key is really to toggle out and back to focus (thanks @Daniel!).

Some small improvements:

No force unwrapping, no need to set ActivationPolicy and call activate twice.

```
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)    

NSRunningApplication.runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.dock").first?.activate(options: [])

OperationQueue.current?.underlyingQueue?.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(200), execute: {
    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
})
```

Comment: I'v used this to fix an issue that locks the interaction with the menu bar, which happens when I use the app's icon (kept in dock) to re-open the app's window that has been previously hidden to enter a statusbar app state

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution that doesn't involve focusing the dock and back, which was causing a flicker as the app exited/entered focus.
This sets the activation policy to prohibited then regular in the next tick:

```swift
if NSApp.activationPolicy() != .regular {
  NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.prohibited)
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(200)) {
      NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
      NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
      window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
  }
} else {
    // activation policy was already regular, just do normal window opening
    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with apple scripts, which **appears** working as expected.

> Except, after closing by key strokes and then reopening a new window (**short time interval**), menu will stay selected.

```
if NSApp.activationPolicy() == .accessory {
    NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
} else {
    var errorDict: NSDictionary?
    NSAppleScript(source: """
        tell application "Dock" to activate current application
        """)?.executeAndReturnError(&errorDict)
    if errorDict != nil{
        print(errorDict!)
        // error executing apple script
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    }
}

window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
```

GIF demo:

[image]

[Video link](https://hdream-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/mengoreo_huadream_com/ER5UjOYwny9NthILGWFUovoBer1sB_q_SaJkoBluYmjeFQ?e=qoQJ7O)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One note: Apple Script won’t work on the Mac App Store. I think it doesn’t even work at all if your app is sandboxed.

Comment: Noted @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I might found another solution for this (which is still an issue on macOS 10.15). I found a similar issue + solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23314366/5218198). The idea is about to show and hide the menuBar for the current application. I needed to run it 2 different run loops but it worked. Here is the solution:

```swift
OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
    NSMenu.setMenuBarVisible(false)
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        NSMenu.setMenuBarVisible(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the menu bar appears, but clicking on the menu bar items does not work.